# Extract figure inside figure using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have came across two `<figure>` nested together while cleaning up a text:

```
text = '<figure><figcaption></figcaption><figure><img alt="dissident1.jpg" class="image-inline" src="https://example.com/dissident1.jpg" title="dissident1.jpg"/><figcaption>A file photo of XXX in prison, provided by his family. Credit: XXX</figcaption></figure><strong>Autopsy demand</strong></figure>'
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
<figure><img alt="dissident1.jpg" class="image-inline" src="https://example.com/dissident1.jpg" title="dissident1.jpg"/><figcaption>A file photo of XXX in prison, provided by his family. Credit: XXX</figcaption></figure><strong>Autopsy demand</strong>
```

---

I've tried to use BeautifulSoup but soup.findAll('figure') returns two figures:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
figure = soup.findAll('figure')
figure[0]
<figure><figcaption></figcaption><figure><img alt="dissident1.jpg" class="image-inline" src="https://example.com/dissident1.jpg" title="dissident1.jpg"/><figcaption>A file photo of XXX in prison, provided by his family. Credit: XXX</figcaption></figure><strong>Autopsy demand</strong></figure>
figure[1]
<figure><img alt="dissident1.jpg" class="image-inline" src="https://example.com/dissident1.jpg" title="dissident1.jpg"/><figcaption>A file photo of XXX in prison, provided by his family. Credit: XXX</figcaption></figure>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [select](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors-through-the-css-property) if required `<figure>` element always inside another `<figure>`

```
text = '<figure><figcaption></figcaption><figure><img alt="dissident1.jpg" class="image-inline" src="https://example.com/dissident1.jpg" title="dissident1.jpg"/><figcaption>A file photo of XXX in prison, provided by his family. Credit: XXX</figcaption></figure><strong>Autopsy demand</strong </figure>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
# figures = soup.select('figure figure')    # multiple nest below
figures = soup.select('figure > figure')    # directly below
for figure in figures:
    print(figure.prettify())
```